# How to move my current using ssh key into Yubikey?

Tags: ssh, gnupg, yubikey

I'm using Yubikey 5 NFC and want to move my openssh key into it so that I can authenticate for ssh login via this Yubikey.

Maybe you will suggest to generate a new gpg keypair for Yubikey and use the gpg-agent instead of ssh-agent to authenticate. But I still want to move my current ssh private key into Yubikey because this way I don't have to edit `authorized_keys` everywhere.

I tried to do this following this article:

https://www.mvps.net/docs/how-to-add-your-existing-ssh-key-to-yubikey-via-openpgp/

which suggest to use `pem2openpgp` from **monkeysphere** to translate my ssh key into gpg key and somehow write this translated gpg key into Yubikey (via `keytocard` command of `gpg`).

But after all these done. I find that the fingerprint of my ssh key is changed, this is confirmed by following command:

```
$ ssh-keygen -lf ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
$ ssh-add -l
```

And the fact that the fingerprint changed makes using my current ssh key meaningless -- I still need to edit `authorized_keys` everywhere to make the "new public key" work.

So is there any other way which can write my old ssh key into Yubikey and keep the old key's fingerprint?